# Can any slicers adjust the layer height based on which layer is being printed? (FDM)

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, layer-height

Hypothetically, if one has a print consisting of very simple shapes at some z-heights but very complicated shapes at other z-heights, it seems like it might be a good idea to run the overall mesh with different layer heights at different parts of the print.

Is there a common way to convince slicers to do this in general?

(Specifically is there any way to make Cura do this?)

Answer (score 2):

[**Adaptive Layers**](https://ultimaker.com/learn/print-detailed-objects-faster-using-adaptive-layers-in-ultimaker-cura) should be the function you are looking for.

[image: Screenshot of Adaptive Layers in Cura]

It allows the slicer to change the layer height dynamically throughout the print, based on the complexity of the geometry being printed. This can lead to improved print quality in areas where high detail is required, while still maintaining print speed in areas where less detail is needed.

PrusaSlicer's equivalent is [**Variable layer height**](https://help.prusa3d.com/article/variable-layer-height-function_1750).

Comment: How exactly does the specified layer height effect this print when this is turned on, do you know?

Comment: @user1833028 Can you explain further this question? Are you asking about the durability, the appearance of the print?

Comment: From the linked site provided by kosteklvp: "Cura’s adaptive layers feature analyzes the slope and angle of the outer wall of the model. The slicing engine will then optimize the layer height for each section. Curves are printed with a finer layer resolution, while vertical, flat areas are printed with thicker layers, often reducing the print duration." This means that when there is a greater slope to a surface, the layer thickness will be adjusted to make layer lines less obtrusive.

Answer (score 0):

Slic3r has an "Adaptive Quality" setting. The roll-over tool tip says, "Automatically determine layer heights by the objects topology instead of using the static value..."

I used it to print a bushing, oriented vertically, with large chamfers on ID and OD. I set layer height to 0.3 mm and turned on Adaptive Quality. Adaptive Quality includes a Quality parameter that I left at the default of 75%. It printed the layers at the chamfers at 0.16 and 0.17 mm and the rest at 0.3 mm layer heights.